# Does action pin multiplicity bounds refer to tokens or values?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

According to [UML documentation](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) (16.2.3.3 Pins):

> A Pin is a kind of ObjectNode (see sub clause 15.4), so it holds *object tokens* that contain *values* of a specified Type (see sub clause 15.2 about tokens). ... A Pin is also a MultiplicityElement. The multiplicity bounds on a Pin constrain the total number of *values* that may be input or output by a single execution of an Action, not the number of *tokens* it contains (see the upperBound property inherited from ObjectNode). ... Pin multiplicity is not unique because it may hold multiple *tokens* with the same *value*.

So it appears that *values* and *tokens* are counted differently, i.e. a pin may hold, say, three tokens all referring to a  a single value. And if pin have `upperBound` (inhireted from ObjectNode) equals to 3 and `lower` (inhereted from MultiplicityElement) equals to 1, it is just fine.

But then 16.2.3.4 Actions and Pins in Activities says:

> Executing an Action in an Activity requires all of its InputPins to be offered all necessary *tokens*, as specified by their *minimum multiplicity* ... When the Action begins executing, all the InputPins accept *tokens* offered to them at once, up to the maximum multiplicity allowed on each InputPin.

So multiplicity refers to number of tokens offered!

Is there any passage in [UML documentation](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)  that resolves the confusion?

Comment: This is really a good one. It might be a bug in the documentation. It's possible to send a bug report, but to my experience you could as well yell into the woods :-/